SSH command variants
Difference between
ssh aryan@za.tryhackme.com 
ssh za\\aryan@thmjmp2.za.tryhackme.com ?
Both login methods are giving me SSH access but some files/folders are accessible via the latter while not via the former?

The command is the same:
ssh [username]@[domain]

The second domain appears to be heading to a "jump-box". (thmjmp2 = try hack me jump 2).
Why things are different is up to what each user account is configured to access and what each domain contains.
